# Dynamic Web mobile Barcode Scanner

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, barcode-scanner

I am trying to develop a web mobile application that can read a bar-code dynamically , which means, I don't have to capture an image, then send it to the server to be scanned, but I want the scan process to be done locally (with JavaScript, jQuery mobile, html5 ...).
I think this question has been already asked, but that was in 2013, so I hope there is a solution now.
share your ideas please.
thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you share the link of the earlier question alongside.

Comment: Are you using phone gap? If so I believe there is a plugin.

Comment: No Mr Phill, I'am using html5, cause I have no idea about phone gap

Comment: You can install a barcode scanner app on a device which register to a certain URL. Then use this URL in your mobile web app. When user arrives to a link, scanner app is opened, user scans the code and the value is returned immediately back to mobile web app. Is this acceptable solution? BTW, if user doesn't have scanner app installed it will be redirected to download it on App store or Google Play.

Comment: yes this solution is acceptable and it works fine, but I found a solution with javascript which is more suitable than the first, thanks for your suggestion :)